# Electrolysis of water using different kind of electrode and electrolyte safest as possible for splitting demonstration

Tags: electrochemistry, water, electrolysis

I am planning to electrolyze water for an experiment. However, I have limited resources and want to do it as safely as possible

> The resources that I have:
>
> - $\pu{12 V}$ DC battery
> - Graphite (in the form of a pencil lead)
> - Stainless Steel
> - Alligator lead clips
> - Sodium Hydroxide ($\ce{NaOH}$)
> - Sodium Sulfate ($\ce{Na2SO4}$)

In such a condition, what would be the best electrode and electrolyte for this experiment?

Comment: What kind of battery and pencil leads? A 12V car battery might burn through your skinny 0.5-0.7mm pencil leads (your "graphite electrodes") rather quickly if your salt solution is conductive enough and/or if the leads are sufficiently close to each other. Not to mention that $\ce{2H2O(\ell) \to 2H2(g) + O2(g)}$ doesn't require that much [overpotential](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Electrolytic_Cells/Electrolysis_I) anyway...

Comment: 12V source would cause a violent rate of electrolysis, if the source is hard, or the source can be  damaged, if it is a soft voltage source without protection. Eventually both. Unless other measures are applied, consider serial resistor $R[\Omega] \approx \frac{10 [V]}{I [A]}$, where I is intended current, safe for both electrolysis and the power source.

Answer (score 0):

Both sodium hydroxide and sulfate will yield same gases on the electrodes but sulfate solution will be neutral $\mathrm{p}H$ so you would want to stick with that. For the electrodes safest option is pure graphite because  stainless steel anode will probably produce hexavalent chromium which is not very good.